# How to find same nodes in neo4j?

Tags: neo4j, cypher

one question about neo4j. I am implementing the data and with a simple cypher query i want to extract the data where the end node is the same for example. 
i have a collection of accountIDs.
`

```
match (n) where n.ID IN ['4260890','04379258','04643207','2250893','228910','2290','225067003','2002755','225832','2138572','4174122','01884','06563','13397','5216','7789','236740'] 
WITH collect (n)  as IDs
UNWIND IDs AS n
```

Now, i want to see which employee id belongs to same department. i tried to do it like,

```
match (n)-[r:Has]-(v) with n, collect (v) as V
Unwind V as Vn
match (m)-[r:Has]-(Vm) with m, collect (Vm) as Va
unwind Va as Vm

Where Vm in Vn
AND NOT 'm'='n'
return distinct n.id as EmpId
collect (distinct Vm) as department
```

But the problem is, i think this query is not correct. I have error on 2nd where clause. 
Can someone help me to find same department shared by the employees of one collection.
Thanks in advnace.

Comment: Can you provide an example dataset and explain the expected output? http://console.neo4j.org/

Comment: are you looking for duplicate nodes or for duplicate relationships? if looking for duplicate nodes, what is the criteria for 2 different nodes to be equal? it seems in your examples that the only criteria for 2 nodes is whether they belong to the same department but that is not a typical scenario for what I can think of.

Comment: also, you collect and then unwind, seems redundant... you could substitute the 1st query for 
```
UNWIND ['4260890','04379258','04643207','2250893','228910','2290','225067003','2002755','225832','2138572','4174122','01884','06563','13397','5216','7789','236740'] 
AS filtered_id 
MATCH (n {id:filtered_id})
RETURN n
```

Comment: thanks, but i want to extract the same department. different nodes of emps belong to same node of department. Like from my data set let us suppose only three Employees belong to same department. Now i want to extract that department and those employees.